# Why does my fflush not work? Skips asking for string in loop

Tags: c, fflush

I am trying to code a lab for class but in the output when I run it it only asks for the string once, and when it loops it skips letting me input it and goes to the next function. I put a `fflush` in there but it does not work. I am using visual studio 2015

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define size 3

struct empsal
{
    char first[15];
    int t1, t2, t3;
    float avg;
    char grade;
};

void load(struct empsal s[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter first name ");
        gets_s(s[i].first);
        printf("Enter 3 test scores ");
        scanf("%d%d%d", &s[i].t1, &s[i].t2, &s[i].t3);
        s[i].avg = (s[i].t1 + s[i].t2 + s[i].t3) / (float)3;
        if (s[i].avg>70)
            s[i].grade = 'p';
        if (s[i].avg<70)
            s[i].grade = 'f';
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}

void print(struct empsal s[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", s[i].first);
        printf("%d %d %d\n", s[i].t1, s[i].t2, s[i].t3);
        printf("Average is %f Grade is %c\n\n", s[i].avg, s[i].grade);
    }
}

//sort
void sort(struct empsal s[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    empsal t;
    for (i = 0; i<n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<n - 1; j++)
        {
            t = s[j];
            s[j] = s[j + 1];
            s[j + 1] = t;
        }
    }
}
//amount passed
void passed(struct empsal s[], int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (s[i].grade = 'p')
            count++;
    }
    printf("Number of passes %d\n\n", count);
}

void main()
{
    empsal s[size];//array
    load(s, size);
    sort(s, size);
    passed(s, size);
    print(s, size);
}
```

OUTPUT:

Enter first name ammar
Enter 3 test scores 90
90
90
Enter first name Enter 3 test scores 80
90
100
Enter first name Enter 3 test scores 90
60
80
Number of passes 3

90 60 80
Average is 76.666664 Grade is p

ammar
90 90 90
Average is 90.000000 Grade is p

80 90 100
Average is 90.000000 Grade is p

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: because `fflush(stdin);` is UB buy standard definition.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - I was slow off the mark there!

Comment: The convention for `#define` is the names are in capitals i.e. `#define SIZE 3`

Comment: Pick a language. Your code looks like C. C and C++ are not the same.

Comment: Don't use any flavour of `gets`, use `fgets`. And don't mix input methods, ie `scanf` and `gets`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - They are not methods - they are functions. This is not OOP land!

Comment: @EdHeal a method is a way of doing something. Sorry for using a perfectly good English word that is not the prerogative of coding speak. OOP has no claim to removing that word from normal usage. After several decades of coding, I do know that C has functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By standard definition `fflush(stdin);` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter 7.21.5.2 (*emphasis mine*)

> If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>   operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

If you want to clean the input buffer of remaining inputs (and newline), do it yourself. A simple approach will be

```
 while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Comment: Suppose there is no more input?

Comment: I said, suppose there is no more input? This function needs an input. For example, after `gets_s` or `fgets` there could be no more input in the buffer.

Comment: ... and when there is, your suggestion will clean it off!